# Less mixin scope problems

Tags: css, less, frontend, mixins

I built a parametric mixin that finds the children of an element based on a "node-value" system that I created. What happens is the children are found by a loop function ".extractArrays" with ".deliverChild" inside it. Then the children (up to 4 of them) are put into ".calculateWidth", which returns the width of the child in a variable (ex. "calculatedWidth1").

The problem is: when there are no third and fourth children, @child3 and @child4 are unset, which creates an error. I set @child3 and @child4 to zero before the mixins, hoping that this would give them default values of 0 before the mixins are called. For some reason, however, when there is a third child, the mixin's returned value of @child3 won't override the @child3 that is set to 0. I am unsure why this is happening, but I feel like there are a couple things that throw me off about Less when it comes to mixins and scope.

```
@child3: none, 0 0, 0, 0;
@child4: none, 0 0, 0, 0;

    .extractArrays(@index, @node, @node-value, @elements-array) when (@index <= @length-elements-array) {
        @element-array: extract(@elements-array, @index);
        @found-node: extract(@element-array, 2);
        .deliverChild(@element-array, @found-node) when (@found-node = @child-node-value1) {
            @child1: extract(@element-array, 1);
        }
        .deliverChild(@element-array, @found-node) when (@found-node = @child-node-value2) {
            @child2: extract(@element-array, 1);
        }
        .deliverChild(@element-array, @found-node) when (@found-node = @child-node-value3) {
            @child3: extract(@element-array, 1);
        }
        .deliverChild(@element-array, @found-node) when (@found-node = @child-node-value4) {
            @child4: extract(@element-array, 1);
        }
        .deliverChild(@element-array, @found-node);
        .extractArrays(@index + 1, @node, @node-value, @elements-array);
    }
    .extractArrays(1, @node, @node-value, @elements-array);


    .calculateWidth(@child1, 1);
    .calculateWidth(@child2, 2);
    .calculateWidth(@child3, 3);

    width: @calculatedWidth1 + @calculatedWidth2 + @calculatedWidth3 + @calculatedWidth4;
```

Comment: Are this found children used anywhere else? I would rather create an array of the found children and calc their width by another loop (or even more simple: calc their width directly within the finding loop). Using an array and a loop to create a bunch of variables with predefined names does not look like a good idea at all (and what if there are 5 of those? 9? 99?).

Comment: In other words I would suggest to redesign this from scratch rather then to try to solve side-effects and problems which are simply unsolvable by the nature of this approach. But to do this we'll need a bit more info on the source array and its elements (specifically how those elements are actually have their `width` defined).

Comment: Creating an array of the found children does sound like a better idea. I did not, however, think this was possible. Less does not seem to be to well documented on the Internet. Can you explain how it is possible to create an array that keeps getting added to by the loop?

Comment: the elements array is an array of "element array"'s, which are comprised of two value: 1. an array that stores a. element or class name b. width and height c. padding d. margin and 2. a number that represents it's place in the DOM. For example 121 and 122 are the first and second children of 12. Also, the width is defined by adding the horizontal properties of the children elements (margin-left, padding-right, width, etc.)

Comment: To answer the initial question about scope: see [Mixins as Functions](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature).

Answer (score 0):

(Not an exact answer to the "scope" question above but an algorithm to use as a starting point in an alternative approach suggested in comments above):

A generic array filtering mixin would look like this (Less 1.7.5 or higher):

```
@array: // key value
    a 1,
    b 2,
    c 3,
    a 4,
    d 5,
    a 6,
    c 7;

// usage:
usage {
   .filter-array(@array, a); 
    result: @filter-array;
}

// impl.:
.filter-array(@array, @key, @key-index: 1) {
    .-(length(@array));
    .-(@i, @r...) when (@i > 0)
        and not(@key = extract(extract(@array, @i), @key-index)) {
            // skip item since key does not match
            .-((@i - 1), @r);
    }
    .-(@i, @r...) when (length(@r) > 0)
        and (@key = extract(extract(@array, @i), @key-index)) {
            // key matches and @r is not empty so concat current item to @r
            .-((@i - 1); extract(@array, @i), @r);
    }
    .-(@i, @r...) when (length(@r) = 0)
        and (@key = extract(extract(@array, @i), @key-index)) {
            // key matches and @r is empty so this is our first item
            .-((@i - 1), extract(@array, @i));
    }
    .-(@i, @r...) when (@i = 0) {
        // define "return" variable:
        @filter-array: @r;
    }
}
```

With resulting array being equal to:

```
@filter-array:
    a 1,
    a 4,
    a 6;
```

This looks quite scary and verbose but still more clean and more controllable than the original approach.

Additionally it would make sense to provide a dedicated mixin to return a sum (or any other "transformation" with result in a single value) of certain values of the array items (that way the implementation can be simplified to a certain point since you won't need to concatenate anything and some of above conditions and/or mixin specializations become unnecessary).

Comment: I believe I understand this, but does less support statements such as "and" and "and not".

Comment: @user1940631 I start to suspect that you've missed [The Docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature-guard-logical-operators) ;).

Comment: I think I'm pretty close, but for the function where @r is not empty and you concat the current item, why is there a semicolon after (@i-1)? Is that a typo or is that the syntax used to specify that "extract(@array, @i), @r)" be made into one value?

Comment: @user1940631, Yes there the `;` is to force the next statement to be interpreted as single value rather than two distinct parameters (i.e. `;` changes the meaning of parameter commas - see [Mixins With Multiple Parameters](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters)).

Comment: The mixin isn't working because the first value being tested isn't a child, which makes it go through the first mixin you wrote, the one with comment "skip item since key does not match". @r is undefined, and then it is put back into the mixin as an undefined value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60581/discussion-between-user1940631-and-seven-phases-max).